# Can't execute commands in Swift on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu-14.04, vapor

I have just installed Swift 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 via Vapor tutorial.

> curl -sL swift.vapor.sh/ubuntu | bash

Here I received information about that clang version >=3.4 is required.
So I manualy have installed clang 3.5 and linked this to clang.

Next I run swift command and try to run any swift command like:

- print("Hello")
- let w = "hello"

But swift ends with segmentation fault.

> Welcome to Swift version 3.0.1 (swift-3.0.1-RELEASE). Type :help for assistance.
>
> 1> print("Hello")
>
> Segmentation fault

Things I have tried

- different swift versions
- different clang versions
- chmod -R o+r on swift folder

Anyone can help?

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be to create an issue on https://bugs.swift.org. They may have seen this before and know what to do.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Actually I have posted my "solution" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. This server was made on OpenVZ virtualization.
Now I have a new one on the KVM and I have made all the same steps and it works...

So solution for my problem was to change virtualization to KVM. Maybe it was a problem of host or OpenVZ itself. No clue.